# How to set a numpy array in loop and plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, odeint

I'm trying to modify a code from the scipy cookbook

The scipy cookbook solves some state equations then prints them:

```
wsol = odeint(two_springs.vectorfield, w0, t, args=(p,),
              atol=abserr, rtol=relerr)

for t1, w1 in zip(t, wsol):
    print t1, w1[0], w1[1], w1[2], w1[3]
```

The scipy cookbook requires you to ru the program and save printed stuff to a file:

program.py > file.dat

then a separate plotting function requires you to load the data from that file

```
t, x1, xy, x2, y2 = loadtxt('two_springs.dat', unpack=True)
```

before plotting

```
plot(t, x1, 'b', linewidth=lw)
plot(t, x2, 'g', linewidth=lw)
```

I just want to set the t,x1,x2 and plot

Can anyone show me how to do that?

This is what I'm trying to modify:

http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/CoupledSpringMassSystem

Comment: So, I don't get your question, you want to avoid the store step? what's the problem then?

Comment: yeah, I want to avoid the store step so I don't have to run the script that stores, then run the one that plots from that every time I change a variable in my state equations. I just want to run one time and be done with it.  

this is the original stuff I'm modifying

http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/CoupledSpringMassSystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `wsol` is Nx4 ndarray, thus you just need to un-pack the values:

```
x1, xy, x2, y2 = wsol.T
```

Comment: Than you, this works. I've seen this .T before, will look up what it actually does